# CSS div sizing relative to viewport borders?

Tags: javascript, css, css-position, positioning

I have a div containing some text and a YouTube video. I used CSS to give it a grey background. I also set the position to 4.4 em from the top, 1% from the left, and made it 98% wide. I want the bottom of the div to be 4.4 em from the bottom, no matter the size or zoom of the browser. How can I do this? Can I use CSS, or is Javascript required? If you give an answer containing Javascript code, please don’t use jQuery.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  width: 98%;
  top: 4.4em;
  background: grey;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
EDIT: Here is my HTML:

<div>
  <h1>A Heading</h1>
  YOUTUBE VIDEO HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you with CSS, you will need to provide both your CSS and your HTML; we can't reproduce your problem without it. Please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: `top: 4.4em; bottom: 4.4em; left: 1%; right: 1%`

Comment: That's still not enough for a minimal example. Having said that, `em` is a font size. You'd be better off using something like `vh` to calculate the height based off the size of the viewport. Or just use `padding` / `margin`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge i have edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use a border that is transparent to simluate the 4.4em gap at the bottom, or you could use the "calc()" css function https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

Example:

```
height: calc(100vh - 4.4em);
```

Comment: It should be 8.8em, but i will accept your answer as soon as i can test that it works on the site.

Comment: It works. I had to do a bit of tweaking, though. Thanks!